# Mutating samples when an entire group meets a condition

Tags: r

I have a large dataset which is broken down into various Zones. I would like to flag when all samples from a given Zone are above a given threshold. If all samples for a given Zone are above a given threshold I need to assign a 1 Value in a separate column (and assign a 2 Value if not all samples in a given Zone are above a given threshold).

I realise I can use the group_by function in dplyr to assign Zones to groups, and that I am essentially needing to mutate the data to a new column, but unsure how to assign a rule that is dependent on all samples from a group meeting a certain condition (in this case being above a given threshold). Below is an example data frame with the threshold value being 1.

```
    Zone Value
1  Zone1     1
2  Zone1     2
3  Zone1     2
4  Zone1     1
5  Zone1     2
6  Zone1     4
7  Zone2     3
8  Zone2     1
9  Zone2     2
10 Zone2     2
11 Zone2     1
12 Zone2     1
13 Zone2     2
14 Zone3     1
15 Zone3     2
16 Zone3     1
17 Zone3     0
18 Zone3     1
19 Zone3     1
20 Zone3     0
21 Zone3     0
```

Below is the desired output. Zones 1 and 2 have New.Values of 1 as all of the samples from these Groups are above the threshold of 1, whole Zone 3 is assigned a 2 as some samples contain values less than 1.

```
    Zone Value New.Value
1  Zone1     1         1
2  Zone1     2         1
3  Zone1     2         1
4  Zone1     1         1
5  Zone1     2         1
6  Zone1     4         1
7  Zone2     3         1
8  Zone2     1         1
9  Zone2     2         1
10 Zone2     2         1
11 Zone2     1         1
12 Zone2     1         1
13 Zone2     2         1
14 Zone3     1         2
15 Zone3     2         2
16 Zone3     1         2
17 Zone3     0         2
18 Zone3     1         2
19 Zone3     1         2
20 Zone3     0         2
21 Zone3     0         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can check if `all` `Value` is `>=1` in each `Zone` and assign value accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Zone) %>% mutate(New_value = c(2, 1)[all(Value >= 1) + 1])
#Can also use if else. 
#df %>% group_by(Zone) %>% mutate(Value = if(all(Value >= 1)) 1 else 2)

#   Zone  Value
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 Zone1     1
# 2 Zone1     1
# 3 Zone1     1
# 4 Zone1     1
# 5 Zone1     1
# 6 Zone1     1
# 7 Zone2     1
# 8 Zone2     1
# 9 Zone2     1
#10 Zone2     1
# … with 11 more rows
```

and in base R :

```
df$New_value <- with(df, c(2, 1)[ave(Value >= 1, Zone, FUN = all) + 1])
```

Comment: Many thanks Ronak! Quick question, I am trying to understand the significance of the '+1' in the event I need to modify this in the future. If I remove '+1' I get the following error "Error: Column `New_value` must be length 6 (the group size) or one, not 2"

Comment: It is a way to convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to numbers. So `FALSE` becomes 1 (`FALSE + 1`) and `TRUE` becomes 2 (`TRUE + 1`) and we use this index to subset `c(2, 1)` values. So since 2 is at position 1, for every `FALSE` value we return 2 and 1 for `TRUE` value. If this is too complex to understand, you can use the `if`/`else` approach in the comment which is simpler to understand I guess. `df %>% group_by(Zone) %>% mutate(Value = if(all(Value >= 1)) 1 else 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using data.table and some dummy data

```
# setup 
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt1 <- data.table(
  V1 = sample(letters[1:5], replace = TRUE, size = 15),
  V2 = sample(c(1:4), replace = TRUE, size = 15))

# solution 
dt1[, V3 := all(V2>1), by = V1]
```

If your dataframe is called `df1` and you want it to be 1 or 2 as the value, the solution would be

```
setDT(df1)
df1[, New.value := sum(all(Value>1)) + 1]
```